# Mocking an Http connection in python

Tags: python, json, http, mocking

I am trying to mock an http connection to test some of my python code. I was wondering how this is achieved. I need the mock class to return data store in a json object when requested. I am trying to figure out how to place the data and create a mock http request in order to obtain it and modify it through posts need be.

Any pointers and small examples are appreciated.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `BaseHTTPServer` module (`http.server` is its name if you're on Python 3) to create a simple HTTP mock server and bend it to your will. It allows you to easily customize its request handlers to achieve anything you need with relatively small amounts of code. The module's documentation is pretty good - [start there](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html).

Comment: If you could suggest something similar for python2.* it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @dustyprogrammer: `BaseHTTPServer` is for Python 2. `http.server` is the new name for this module in Python 3 (I also clarified the answer a bit)

Answer (score 1):

I had the the same requirement few days back. I used [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) webserver. Extremely easy to use and very well documented. It has jsonify function which will help you returning json.

To be honest every framework will provide you jsonify equivalent, just that I found flask to easy to understand and setup for my testing need.